# C++ Noob function cant figure out parameters of a call?

Tags: c++

I can't figure out the parameters of my call! These are my prototypes:

```
void printIdInfo(ofstream &, string , string , const string, string, const string);
void getreadExpression(ifstream &fin, double &operand1, char &oper, double &operand2);
void echoExpression (ofstream &fout, double &, char &, double &);
```

These are my definitions that go below main...

```
void getprintIdInfo (ofstream &fout, string &first_name, string &last_name, const string CLASS, string lecture_section, const string DUE_DATE) {
  fout << first_name << " " << last_name << endl
       << CLASS << lecture_section << endl << DUE_DATE << endl;
}

void readExpression (ifstream &fin, double &operand1, char &oper, double &operand2) {
  fin >> operand1 >> oper >> operand2;
}

void echoExpression (ofstream &fout, double & operand1, char &oper, double &operand2) {
  fout << operand1 << " " << oper << " " << operand2;
}
```

And these are my calls but theyre not working at all my parameters arent making sense but i dont know how to correct it. thanks in advance.

```
printIdInfo(ostream & out, first_name&, last_name&, lecture_section&);
getreadExpression(fin&, operand1&, oper&, operand2&);
echoExpression(fout&, operand1&, oper&, operand2&);
```

Comment: Take away the `&` from your calls.

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Your function names don't match up across the snippets you've posted.

Comment: im sorry the printidinfo and echoexpression shouldnt have get in their name i redid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  getprintIdInfo (out, first_name, last_name, lecture_section);
  getreadExpression (fin, operand1, oper, operand2);
  getechoExpression (fout, operand1, oper, operand2);
```

Your first call is *maybe* attempting to declare an `ostream` reference and use it as an argument, I don't know wha tyou are trying to do there. The others don't need the `&` suffix. Actually, the `&` suffix after an identifier is not even legal syntax. When you have an argument that takes a pointer, you can use the address-of operator to get it `getInfo( &out )`. When the argument takes a reference, there is no need for you to write anything additional but just the variable to be referenced.

Answer (score 3):

When you're making the call, do not use the ampersand. It is already determined in the prototype that it is a reference to a variable. When you use the ampersand in your call, you are performing a binary AND operation.